# accidentally deleted administrative account in registry

Tags: windows, windows-registry, user-accounts

my password for unlock screen in wondows 10 wouldn't work so I used registry to delete my administrative user account accidentally.  How do I use the builtin local admin account to fix it?

Comment: Restore the registry from the backup you made before changing it?

Comment: Did you create a Windows State setpoint before mucking with the registry? Always a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't came across this, but would enabling the default administrator account work in your case?
[How to enable the hidden Windows 10 administrator account](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/11/12/how-to-enable-the-hidden-windows-10-administrator-account/)

**Edited:** 
 
To enable the Windows 10 administrator account do the following:
1.  Tap on the Windows-key. This should open the start menu or bring you to the Start Screen interface depending on how Windows 10 is configured on the system.
2.  Type cmd and wait for the results to be displayed.
3.  Right-click no the Command Prompt result and select "run as administrator" from the context menu.
4.  Run the command net user to display a list of all user accounts on the system.
5.  To activate the inactive administrator account, run the command net user administrator /active:yes
6.  If you want to enable the guest account as well run the command net user guest /active:yes

Note: You might need to proceed this with an Admin account. Therefore, this might actually be irrelevant

Comment: You cannot do this from a non admin account unfortunately.

Comment: @Moab Actually, I think it's rather fortunate - it would be quite bad if anybody could enable a super-powerful account and start using it. Either way, answer writers should include the relevant parts of articles in the answer in case links break.

Comment: Good edit  removed my -1

Comment: "help I deleted my administrator account" ..."you can solve this problem with an administrator account" I am lost how is the user suppose to use this solution without an Administrator account?